# How to play it on fullscreen python cv2

Tags: python, opencv

How do I play the video.mp4 in fullscreen instead of playing it in a window
and is there any way to play video with audio without playing the audio separately?

```
import cv2
from playsound import playsound
from threading import Thread
   
def func1():
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture("video.mp4")
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    while(1):
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(33) & 0xFF == ord('q') or ret==False :
            cap.release()
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break
        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)

def func2():
    playsound('6989946141014084358.mp3')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Thread(target = func1).start()
    Thread(target = func2).start()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to setup the window ahead of time (e.g. before your blocking while loop):

```
cv2.namedWindow('frame',cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.setWindowProperty('frame',cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN,cv2.WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)
```